# Is it possible to set up Merlin environment for MetaOCaml?

Tags: ocaml, metaocaml, merlin

Is it possible to set up Merlin environment for [MetaOCaml](http://okmij.org/ftp/ML/MetaOCaml.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merlin compiles just fine with metaocaml, but obviously it doesn't understand BER syntax, so only the most basic features are working and types are not precise for meta code.

Comment: Alex says:
following your [question on Github][1], MetaOCaml support was merged in [October 2015][2], enabling it via `EXT Meta` in [`.merlin`][3].)


  [1]: https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/issues/408
  [2]: https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#merlin-23
  [3]: https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/wiki/project-configuration